# Array into array using array_push key issue

Tags: php, arrays

I'm getting confused about how to insert array into array and give it a key name. **Not number!**.

I have the main array, which contains info about customer. the sub array should be called **["verlauf"]**.

The **["verlauf"]** array conatins multiple arrays ( as same as db row count ). the main idea is that the sub array should be having the key name **["verlauf"]**. in my code im getting the **[0]** as key.

Current array output:

```
array(19) { 
    ["id"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["name"]=> string(11) "qwert zuiop" 
    ["email"]=> string(23) "xy@gmail.com" 
    ["phn_num"]=> string(12) "123456789" 
    [0]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> array(4) {
            ["datum"]=> string(10) "30.07.2020"
            ["uhr_zeit"]=> string(5) "22:25"
            ["status"]=> string(1) "0"
            ["info"]=> string(34) "some info"
        }
        [1]=> array(4) {
            ["datum"]=> string(10) "30.07.2020"
            ["uhr_zeit"]=> string(5) "23:25"
            ["status"]=> string(1) "1"
            ["info"]=> string(34) "some info"
        }
    }
}
```

what i want is that the `[0]` on line 6 in the above example to be `["verlauf"]`

My PHP:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     $verlaufArray[] = array(
          "datum"    => $row['datum'],
          "uhr_zeit" => $row['uhr_zeit'],
          "status"   => $row['status'],
          "info"     => $row['info']);
}
array_push($returnArray, $verlaufArray);
```

Please note that `$returnArray` is the "main array".

Comment: `$returnArray['verlauf'] = $verlaufArray;` ?

Comment: him.. that is imperessing. how could i miss that. it works. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do that by using associate array-

Your PHP code -

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     $verlaufArray[] = array(
          "datum"    => $row['datum'],
          "uhr_zeit" => $row['uhr_zeit'],
          "status"   => $row['status'],
          "info"     => $row['info']);
}
$returnArray['verlauf'] = $verlaufArray;
```

Comment: To elaborate a bit: Take a look at the documentation for [`array_push()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php). All it does is add the variable to the end, and since it doesn't provide a key, it will use the first available index. It's better to use bracket notation when adding single elements or when you need to specify a key. OP's problem can be simulated with `$returnArray[] = $verlaufArray;` - since there'd be no key, it would get appended with the first available index.

Comment: @Xhynk thank you for the explain. really helped me man.

Comment: Thank you for more explanation. Feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: What is the need for the loop at all if the keys are identical to the original ones?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to complicate things so much. It looks like you need just one line of code.

```
$returnArray['verlauf'] = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

There's no need for the `while` loop if the structure remains the same. [`fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) will give you an array containing associative results from your query.

Comment: Thank you. The structure is not staying the same. there are some other rows going into other array. also im not using the class style